# SQL Server - Join a selection of columns from a Dynamically Pivoted Table

Tags: select, dynamic, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I try to dynamically pivot the table PMESATOVERVIEW and join it towards PMEOBJECT another table with the code below. However I want to drop certain columns from the pivoted table.

SQL Example: http://rextester.com/DKHF52968

First I will describe the data example:

```
PMEOBJECT
ObjectId, Location,
1, North
2, South
3, West
4, East
```

And inner join the pivoted version of this table:

```
PMESATOVERVIEW
ObjectId, AttributeCat, AttributeId, Value
1, WW, Surface, 40
1, XX, Date, 1-1-2017
1, WW, Energy Label, B
2, WW, Surface, 45
2, XX, Date, 3-5-2017
3, WW, Surface, 50
3, WW, Energy Label, A
4, WW, Surface, 50
4, XX, Date, 1-4-2018
4, WW, Energy Label, A+
```

With the following code:

```
DECLARE @colsValues 

AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff(
(SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 
    Quotename(fat.ATTRIBUTEID)
     FROM   PMESATOVERVIEW fat
     FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =  
                                'SELECT    *
                                  FROM       (SELECT *
                                              FROM   PMESATOVERVIEW
                                              PIVOT(Max(VALUE)
                                              FOR ATTRIBUTEID IN ('+ 
@colsValues +')) piv) fat
                                  INNER JOIN PMEOBJECT tb
                                  ON          tb.OBJECTID = fat.OBJECTID';
EXECUTE(@query)
```

This code works without an error, but the result I get is:

```
PMESATOVERVIEW
ObjectId    AttributeCat    Date    Energy Label    Surface ObjectId    Location
1   WW  NULL        C       40      1   North
2   WW  NULL        B       40      2   West
3   WW  NULL        A+      45      3   South
4   WW  NULL        NULL    50      4   East
1   XX  1-1-2017    NULL    NULL    1   North
2   XX  3-4-2017    NULL    NULL    2   West
4   XX  1-5-2018    NULL    NULL    4   East
```

And what I want is:

```
ObjectId    Date    Energy Label    Surface ObjectId    Location
1   1-1-2017    C       40  1   North
2   3-4-2017    B       40  2   West
3   NULL        A+      45  3   South
4   1-5-2018    NULL    50  4   East
```

The SQL statement result: http://rextester.com/DKHF52968

Any ideas how to do it?
I tried to SELECT only a few columns within the Pivot statement, but somehow it won't recognize ObjectId, AttributeId and Value.

Any ideas on this?

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

By doing something like, you could get the expected output. 
But, there might be better ways to do this.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(AttributeId) 
         FROM   PMESATOVERVIEW       
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @maxCols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', max(' + Quotename(AttributeId) + ') as ' + Quotename(AttributeId)
         FROM   PMESATOVERVIEW       
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =  'SELECT     fat.ObjectId, '+@maxCols+',  max(tb.location) as Location 
                                    FROM       (SELECT ObjectId, '+ @cols +'
                                                FROM   PMESATOVERVIEW 
                                                PIVOT(Max(Value) FOR AttributeId IN ('+ @cols +')) piv) fat
                                    INNER JOIN PMEOBJECT tb 
                                    ON         tb.ObjectId = fat.ObjectId 
                                    group by   fat.ObjectId';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+----------+
| ObjectId |   Date   | Energy Label | Surface | Location |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+----------+
|        1 | 1-1-2017 | C            |      40 | North    |
|        2 | 3-4-2017 | B            |      40 | West     |
|        3 | NULL     | A+           |      45 | South    |
|        4 | 1-5-2018 | NULL         |      50 | East     |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

Online Demo: http://rextester.com/GVY57614